# Qemu built from source doesn't work with --enable-kvm flag on RHEL-7 but suprisingly works on CentOS-7

Tags: qemu, kvm

I am trying to build and run QEMU from its source with --enable-kvm flag. The suprising fact is qemu with --enable-kvm flag works like a charm on CentOS 7 (Server as well as on workstation) but it hangs terribly on RHEL 7 server.

I am using Linux From sratch guide to build the system link : http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/postlfs/qemu.html

I have tested the vmx flag using the script

```
grep -E "(vmx|svm)" /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
4
```

On Rhel as well as centos I have downloaded the dependencies using following script.

```
#!/bin/sh
yum install gcc
yum install zlib-devel
yum install gnutls-devel
yum install libgcrypt-devel
yum install glibc-devel
yum install glib2-devel
yum install pixman-devel
```

Then I used following script to compile the build

```
if [ $(uname -m) = i686 ]; then
   QEMU_ARCH=i386-softmmu
else
   QEMU_ARCH=x86_64-softmmu
fi

sed -i 's/ memfd_create/ qemu_memfd_create/' util/memfd.c &&

mkdir -vp build &&
cd        build &&

../configure  --target-list=$QEMU_ARCH \
              --enable-gnutls          \
              --enable-gcrypt &&

unset QEMU_ARCH &&
make &&
make-install
```

After this I am trying to boot an encrypted virtual disk using the command.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -daemonize -display none \
-net user,hostfwd=tcp::3000-:22,hostfwd=tcp::8080-:8080,hostfwd=tcp::80-:80,hostfwd=tcp::443-:443 -net nic \
-object secret,id=secmaster0,format=base64,file=key.b64 \
-object secret,id=sec0,keyid=secmaster0,format=base64,\
data=$SECRET,iv=$(<iv.b64) \
-drive if=none,driver=luks,key-secret=sec0,\
id=drive0,file.driver=file,\
file.filename=prod.luks \
-device virtio-blk,drive=drive0 -m 5120
```

Then, I just ssh in the daemonised kvm. The point is everything works like a charm in CentOS but in RHEL 7 I am not able to ssh in the machine.

If I remove `--enable-kvm` flag I am able to ssh in.

I have already spent a lot of time experimenting over it and I simply don't understand what is going wrong. I am no pro on this topic just trying to find a fix for a niche problem. Any guidance on debuging the qemu or any guidance or reference to documents/mailing-list thread/forum is deeply appreciated.

Peace.

**Update**

As mentioned by @Peter Maydell in the comments, I started the qemu without the display none flag. It started a vnc, I connnected with the vnc and it seems kvm doesn't seem to boot the hard disk. It is stuck on 
`Booting from Hard Disk ...`

Comment: The information you need to debug is likely in the guest, in its logging that it displays at bootup and so on. To start with I recommend dropping the -daemonize and -display none. Check that it actually boots OK using its console to interact with it, and read the boot messages to see whether anything is different about its attempts to initialize its networking and its ssh daemon between the two cases.

Comment: Okay I started it without daemonize. It started vnc by default. On connecting with vnc, the system is stuck on booting from harddisk

Comment: @DanielB If he could give it a shot. It would be super awesome. As I have learned how to use luks following his tutorials/slides/posts